# Как наследовать шаблонный класс?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Как создать обычный (не шаблонный класс), который наследовал бы шаблонный  без явного определения типа? Хочу сделать подобие итератора,

```
template <class T> class Iterator : public New_List_<T>
{...}
```

но если его(`class Iterator`) не сделать шаблонным

```
class Iterator : public New_List_<T>
{...}
```

выходит ошибка синтаксиса, до компиляции.
Выход есть выставить определенный тип к примеру int

```
class Iterator : public New_List_<int>
{...}
```

Но хочется избежать этой ситуации и не делать случай частным.

> UPD

Но кто писал STL контейнер (к примеру)List не мог же засунуть внутрь основного класса класс итератор, как то это наверное "рефакторилось"? Просто если даже перегрузить некоторые операторы к примеру = может получится следующая громоздкая реализация

```
template <class T> Iterator<T> *Iterator<T>::operator=(New_List_<T> *List)
{
    Iterator = List;
    return this;
}
```

и при вызове этого сего будет выглядеть, не так

```
std::list<int>::iterator iter = v.begin();
```

а так `std::list<int>::iterator<int> iter = v.begin();`

Конечно если я прав, - не компилил.

Comment: А шаблон нельзя использовать без явного определения типа. Если вы хотите вместо `int` использовать произвольный тип - то это как раз то, для чего в языке сделаны шаблоны.

Comment: Подумайте сами - ваш `Iterator` зависит от того, какой тип будет использоваться в базовом классе. Так? Т.е. он сам является шаблонным... `Iterator`, у которого базовый `New_List_<int>`, отличается от того, у которого базовый `New_List_<double>` - это разные классы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как раз засунуть итератор внутрь основного класса и позволит писать `std::list<int>::iterator` вместо `std::vector<int>::iterator<int> iter = v.begin();`. Засунуть можно двумя способами:

1. создав внутренний класс

```
template<typename T> class
list
{
    public: class
    iterator
    {
...
```

2. объявив алиас для внешнего класса

```
template<typename T> class
list_iterator
{
...

template<typename T> class
list
{
    public: using
    iterator = list_iterator<T>;
...
```